# VSCode - PHP all Style Linebreaks in Autocomplete Code Blocks

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've setup PHP IntelliSense to use [Allman Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Brace_placement_in_compound_statements) linebreaks, so when I use `CTRL+K+F` it will successfully reformat from this:

```
if (condition) {
    // code...
} else {
    // code
}
```

To this (Allman style):

```
if (condition)
{
    // code...
}
else
{
    // code
}
```

What I cannot get working is how to get VSCodes auto-complete functions to format the same way:

[image]

I want braces to be on a new line, but nothing I've found, even extensions, seems to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this out, it's called a Snippet, and you can configure them via

- `CTRL+SHIFT+P`
- `Snippets: Configure User Snippets`
- Then create a new one or extend from the list

If you want to add a PHP user snippet to use with HTML, then add your php tag to the html snippet.

You can use variables `$1` `$2` `$3` to allow you to tab through components of snippet once it outputs.